# On page load listview searching I don't know how to bind data

Tags: asp.net

Help me on page load to bind data on search side when I search the username, I don't know how to bind data to the data view:

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Users WHERE [UserID] = @UserID" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserRoles = 'Admin'" 

        UpdateCommand="UPDATE Users SET [Gender] = @Gender,[Username] = @Username,[Name] = @Name,[Address]=@Address,[State]=@State,[ZipCode]=@ZipCode,[Phone]=@Phone,[EmailAdd]=@EmailAdd,[City]=@City WHERE [UserID] = @UserID">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

if (txtsearchstaff.Text != " " && txtsearchstaff.Text != "")
        {
            string strConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConString);
            string cmd = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username=@Search";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, myConnect);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", txtsearchstaff.Text);

           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
          /*  da.Fill(ds, );

            ListView1.DataSource = da;
            ListView1.DataBind();*/

            ListView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["table"];
           ListView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `SqlCommand` object to execute the query and then bind the `SqlDataReader` to the list view, like this:

```
string strConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

// Create a connection object, which gets disposed of by using block
using(var myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConString))
{
    // Make parameterized query to be executed by the command object
    string query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username=@Search";

    // Create a command object to execute query, which gets disposed of by using block
    using(var theCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnect))
    {
        // Add the value for the @Search parameter
        theCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", txtsearchstaff.Text.Trim());

        // Open the connection as late as possible
        myConnect.Open();

        // Store results of query in reader
        var theReader = theCommand.ExecuteRead();

        // Bind reader to list view
        ListView1.DataSource = theReader;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, myConnect);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", txtsearchstaff.Text);
got error

Comment: ok now it work but when i press edit it occur error 
The ListView 'ListView1' raised event ItemEditing which wasn't handled.

Comment: if control on server side i need to delete  datasourceID?<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="UserID" 
        DataSourceID="">

Comment: how to set when this button is click i set the id to sqldatasource1?
  <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" CausesValidation="False" CssClass="buttonBorder" OnClientClick="return validate();"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;